# Where can I find End of Life Support Dates for Microsoft Products?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2014, end-of-life

Specifically, I would like the the End of Life Support Dates for these:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try Microsoft's EOL Search

There is a Website for this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search

Here are the searches for the products you asked about:

- **W2012r2:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=%5C%22windows%20server%202012%20r2%20%5C%22
- **MSSQL2014:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=%5C%22SQL%20server%202014%20%5C%22